# What are the possible issues with generating random numbers in OpenSSL this way

Tags: openssl, random

My following method is supposed to generate random numbers using OpenSSL. Is this correct and sufficient? Or do you see any issues with it?

```
vector<unsigned char> generateBytes(const unsigned char* seed, const size_t length)
{
     if (seed != nullptr)
          RAND_seed(seed, length);  // No error handling is necessary here??
     else 
         /*Do I need to do something here to correctly autoseed the PRNG */

     vector<unsigned char> result(length);   

     if (!RAND_bytes(result.data(), length)) {
            throw Exception("Could not get random bytes.");
     }
     return result;
}
```

I also have the following concerns regarding standard practice:

- Is it common practice to use the Engine APIs even when using the default SSLeay engine?
- Is it common practice to auto-seed the PRNG from a entropy pools like /dev/random irrespective of how OpenSSL auto-seeds upon initialization?
- Is it a common practice to set ENTROPY_NEEDED to some value?